# Orbeon - Dynamic dropdown - search dont work

Tags: orbeon

I have problem with dynamic dropdown with search. Search dont work and dropdown then have no data. Without search everything works. I have form witch work in Orbeon 2020 but after update to 2021 it stop working. I try example from documentation (https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/component/static-dynamic-dropdown) with countries. It not workion in Orbeon 2021 but same form work in Orbeon 2020. Can be problem with {$fr-search-value} in new Orbeon versions?

Here is example https://demo.orbeon.com/demo/fr/orbeon/builder/edit/e1ee06b8fe844e5c9fab04ac1dc72959302d0ba3

Comment: David, as mentioned in my answer below, the issue you've hit has been fixed, but as of this writing, Orbeon Forms 2021.1.2 isn't released yet. Are you using Orbeon Forms PE? If so just let me know if having a pre-release build with that issue fixed would help. -Alex

Comment: Yes, I'm using Orbeon Forms 2021.1 PE . My colleague will contact you. Thank you!

Comment: Perfect David, and while we wait for the 2021.1.2 release, I've also just sent a 2021.1.1+ build with that fix to David H. on Basecamp. -Alex

Comment: Yes, new version 2021.1.2 fix this issue. Thank you

Comment: Excellent David, and thank you for the confirmation. -Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've hit [issue #5204](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/5204), which is fixed in Orbeon Forms PE 2021.1.2.